# Differential Delay Equations

Tags: reference-request, delay-differential-equations

What are some good introductory references for differential delay equations? I am especially interested in coupled systems of differential delay equations.

Comment: Did you consider this one? M. Lakshmanan, D.V. Senthilkumar "Dynamics of Nonlinear Time-Delay Systems"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, some recent books are [An Introduction to Delay Differential Equations with Applications to the Life Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441976450) by Smith, Springer 2010 and [Applied Delay Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387743715) by Erneux, Springer 2009. Chapter 8 of the latter book discusses coupled oscillators.