# How to solve $f'(x)=f(x+1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Are there non-trivial solutions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ of the following "differential equation"?

$$f'(x)=f(x+1).$$

I consider $f(x)=0$ as trivial solution. I tried to express $f$ as a power series, i.e. $f(x)=\sum_n a_n/n!\cdot x^n$. This brought me to the following identity for the coefficients:

$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {a_{k+n}}{k!}.$$

This does not really help, as the right side contains infinitely many coefficients itself. And infinitely many must be non-zero. I expect that a possible solution looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: A complex one: let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be the solution to $\alpha = e^\alpha$, which is $\alpha \approx 0.318132 - 1.33724i$.

Consider $f(z) = e^{\alpha z}$.

$$f'(z) = \alpha e^{\alpha z}= e^\alpha e^{\alpha z} = e^{\alpha(z+1)} = f(z+1)$$

Comment: It's not continuous, but can $e^{\{x\}}$ where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ qualify ? Since it is periodic, $f(x+1)=f(x)$ so we arrive at $f'=f$ which is simply exponential, (at the expense of small issues at the bounds).

Comment: @zwim and mechanodroid: Very nice ideas! Unfortunatly I am looking for differentiable and real valued solutions.

Comment: @mechanodroid: That equation has a lot of solutions. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/858985/8157

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It's not the same equation: this one is $z = e^z$, that one is $ze^z = a$. Regardless, it's just important that a solution exists.

Comment: @mechanodroid $\alpha=W(-1)$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function. Choose branch appropriately.

Comment: You can combine $e^{\alpha x}$ and $e^{\bar\alpha x}$ (which is also a solution) to get a real valued continuous function, e.g. $e^{(\Re\alpha) x}\cos((\Im\alpha)x)$

Comment: This is a "delay differential equation" ... see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514618/differential-delay-equations

Comment: Technically this is not a delay differential equation, as the derivative is determined by values to the right of $x$, not the left.

Comment: Have you tried a Laplace Transform?

Comment: @mechanodroid: Then see here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859274/8157

Comment: general solution https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4379608/532409